ParallelTable: an unknown box name (TerminatedEvaluation) was sent as the box form for the expression
This seems to be a bug?
The example code for MMA v.13.0 is:
propf[p_?NumericQ] := 
  ParametricNDSolve[{f''[x] + (1^2 + p^2) f[x] == 0, f[t0] == y/2, 
    f'[t0] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 10}, {y}, PrecisionGoal -> 14, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10];
propagatortable = ParallelTable[k^2 (f /. propf[k]), {k, 10, 100, 1}]

Just a klein gordon operator. Doing this yields the error message in the title. But no evaluation should terminate.
In fact, using Table instead works.
Can anyone reproduce the problem and or offer a solution? ParallelTable is nicer since the calculation take longer in truth.

@Domen It technically does yes. So I would in my case use ParallelDo and set up the propf everytime right? And just add this to a table which I share with all my subkernels?

It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve with this parallelization. Also, there are still some parameters left in your DEs. Why don't you do propf = ParametricNDSolve[..., f, {x, 0, 10}, {y, p, t0}];?

Each evaluation for one $k$ takes quite some time (not here, but in real life), so I'd like to repeat this using parallelization. I realized that I did not replace $t_0$ with 0 here in this. Sorry about that. $y$ ranges from 0 to 10, if you wanna know, just like $x$.

@Domen Ok, actually, yeah, the parameters don't make any sense here, but it really was to only demonstrate the error, not actually have any useful applications.

Let me give you a shorter example of a working code: ClearAll[propf]; propf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[x] == p  f[x], f[0] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 10}, p]; ParallelTable[propf[p], {p, 0, 5}]

@Domen So you mean I could also (now again using my example) take $p$ as another parameter of ParametricNDSolve and then ParallelTable works, rather than having this function construction with $p$ as an argument.

Yes! You just one ParametricNDSolveValue, put all relevant parameters in it, and it should work.
